# Send Data From firebase Firestore To Salesforce

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, salesforce, crm

We are using Firestore as a primary DB for a web application. We are trying to integrate Salesforce.And the goal is make salesforce and Firestore in sync.

We are thinking of using salesforce APIs to send data from Firestore to salesforce. similarly, building REST API's to update data changes from salesforce to Firestore. But it might affect the application's performance. Is there any way to make salesforce and Firestore to be in sync?

Comment: No easy way for sure, especially if you don't know exactly which data to sync and when. It starts with Salesforce not really being a database. You can check Mulesoft, tray.io, workato, zapier as "product solutions" or you can try building it yourself with cloud functions & the Salesforce REST API (beware there are many edge cases and small issues you will encounter).
For people to help you here I think you need to formulate the question more precisely, as it stands it is too broad.
Best of luck :)

Comment: Can Firestore talk to OData-compatible database? Read a bit about "Lightning Connect". Can you listen to cometd / bayeux protocol events? They could be sent near-realtime from SF (read about "change data capture" or "platform events")... It feels like you'll need some middleware...